# Doing a continuous action while a TButton is held down

Tags: delphi

How would I be able to do a continuous action while a button is held down? For example, I have made a custom 'Numpad' for my application, which has a <kbd>Delete</kbd> button. As of right now, I have to click it separately, but I want it to keep deleting while it is held down.

```pascal
procedure TFrame1.deleteClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MiString: string;
begin
  global_gotten_mode := precheck.global_edit_mode;
  precheck.Form2.input_field.SetFocus;
  MiString := Copy(precheck.Form2.input_field.Text, 0, (length(precheck.Form2.input_field.Text) - 1));
  precheck.Form2.input_field.Text := MiString;
  Form2.input_field.SelStart := high(integer);
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a timer and activate it on the `OnMouseDown` event.
As long as the button is held down, the timer will kick in at a rate of your choice.
When the button is released, the `OnMouseUp` event disables the timer.

Something in this way:

```
procedure TFrame1.BtnMouseDown(Sender : TObject);
begin
  global_gotten_mode := precheck.global_edit_mode;
  precheck.Form2.input_field.SetFocus;
  fMyBtnTimer.Interval := 500;  // Initial repetition rate
  fMyBtnTimer.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TFrame1.BtnMouseUp(Sender : TObject);
begin
  fMyBtnTimer.Enabled := false;
end;

procedure TFrame1.MyBtnTimerEvent(Sender : TObject);
var
  MiString: string;
begin
  fMyBtnTimer.Interval := 200;  // Increase repetition rate
  MiString := Copy( precheck.Form2.input_field.Text, 
                    0, 
                    length(precheck.Form2.input_field.Text) - 1);
  precheck.Form2.input_field.Text := MiString;
  Form2.input_field.SelStart := high(integer);
end;
```